# How to hide/display separate forms using buttons and redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm new to react and redux (and posting on stack overflow!).

I'd like to hide/display a redux-form based on a button choice.

I have two buttons: Option-A and Option-B.

I followed the redux tutorial exactly to have their onClick methods dispatch `setVisibilityFilter(buttonprops.filter)` through a container. [See: FilterLink.js](https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist) This works fine and updates the state's visibilityFilter with the corresponding option.

However, I'm stuck about how I should access the state's filter to hide/display different forms. I would like something similar to what formValueSelector does, but it isn't applicable for buttons (because they don't return values?)

This is my main component's code:

```
class MainForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { error } = this.props
    return ( 
      <Grid.Column width={9}>
        <Button.Group floated='right'>
        <FilterLink filter={VisibilityFilters.SHOW_A}>A</FilterLink>
        <Button.Or />
        <FilterForm filter={VisibilityFilters.SHOW_B}>B</FilterLink>
        </Button.Group>
        /* If SHOW_A, display FORM_A, else if SHOW_B, display FORM_B */
    </Grid.Column> 
  )
}}
```

I feel like just toying with the state directly now would waste the effort of implementing redux. I think I should be passing the value as a prop down to the child forms, but I'm confused how to do so, especially because I don't know how I would get that value without changing my onClick anyway, and onClick is already defined in FilterLink.js

There must be some way to access my state visibility filter to hide/display a form, just unsure how to get there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/introduction/quick-start), you can pass anything from the Redux Store to your component through its props.

So based on the link you posted, this should work:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class MainForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { error, visibilityFilter } = this.props
    return ( 
      <Grid.Column width={9}>
        <Button.Group floated='right'>
        <FilterLink filter={VisibilityFilters.SHOW_A}>A</FilterLink>
        <Button.Or />
        <FilterForm filter={VisibilityFilters.SHOW_B}>B</FilterLink>
        </Button.Group>
        {visibilityFilter === VisibilityFilters.SHOW_A
          ? <FormA />
          : <FormB />
        }
    </Grid.Column> 
  )
}}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  visibilityFilter: state.visibilityFilter
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainForm)
```

Comment: @Sandra You can upvote and accept the answer with the buttons on the left of this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have connected the component you want to conditionally render things to the redux store.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({visibleFilter: state.visibilityFilter})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainForm)
```

Then you can access this information in your connected component's props, e.g.

```
render() {

  return {

     {this.props.visibleFilter === VisibilityFilters.SHOW_A && (<FormA /> )}

     {this.props.visibleFilter === VisibilityFilters.SHOW_B && (<FormB /> )}

   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) actually now I have a separate issue.. after clicking a button, it'll display the right form, but both buttons become nonfunctional. All the focus seems to be on the form, and the buttons are stuck in their state unless I refresh the page. It seems like the issue is around using redux-form, because if I try displaying normal fields like input, the top buttons still work normally, unlike how they freeze when I display a redux-form after.